# Problems with Summernote and crispy-forms in Django

Tags: python, django, summernote, django-crispy-forms

I have 2 problems: (1) I got Summernote working in the admin create-a-post section, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into the publicly-facing HTML form (at https://example.com/post/new/), and (2) I'm using crispy_forms, and when I make a post in Summernote in admin with a picture and/or some HTML formatting tags, the post renders as plain-text, including the HTML tags, which is ugly.

I've tried removing the crispy tag and replacing it with the "safe" keyword, but the HTML still renders in plain-text. How do I get Summernote to render properly with crispy_forms? Here's my code:

**post_form.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**the main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),

    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),

    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
        ListView,
        DetailView,
        CreateView,
        UpdateView,
        DeleteView
)
from .models import Post


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from . import models

from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']

    content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget())
```

**from settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',
    'django_summernote',
]
```

```
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap4"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?